# PHP Time comparison using this exact format

Tags: php, time

How do I compare a time written in this format with the current time to see if this exact moment has happened yet (It's for a countdown timer), but the time must be in this format:

`12/31/2012 5:00 AM UTC-0500`

Ultimately I want to say if the current time is less than that date, display this, otherwise, display this.

Comment: convert the date using strtotime, after converting it you can compare it then convert it again by using date function in the format that you want, then insert it into your database, display it, or do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtotime can convert string dates to unix timestamp which you can easily use later for comparisons/etc

```
$timestamp = strtotime("12/31/2012 5:00 AM UTC-0500");
if (time() > $timestamp)
...
```